# Creating database SQL script with login no password SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run some scripts from C# and I have a script `createdb.sql`.

When I execute it I get an error because login failed for `mycompany\myname`

This is the script

```
Use Master
-- Drop the database if it already exists
IF  EXISTS (SELECT name 
                  FROM sys.databases 
                  WHERE name = N'TestDB')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
        DROP DATABASE TestDB
        CREATE DATABASE TestDB 
        ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET MULTI_USER
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        CREATE DATABASE TestDB
```

What do I need to do to create a simple login as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mycompany\myname" looks like a domain login.

For "Windows security" SQL takes the currently logged on user, it's difficult to impersonate another user to run SQL commands (but not impossible).

You can create a simpler SQL Login by following the [instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) this will allow you to supply credentials in the connection string

Comment: Its windows security.Can I create everything from a sql script?

Comment: As per the linked page, use the CREATE LOGIN Transact-SQL command

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign the Windows user sysadmin permissions (or at least greater security permissions) to be able to do that in the master database.